# Duplicate class org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder while using Jitsi Sdk and quickblox-android-sdk

Tags: android, webrtc, quickblox, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

I am using

**com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-videochat-webrtc:3.9.1** for Chat

and

**org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:2.10.0** //for Meeting

but unable to resolve these issues

> Duplicate class org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder found in modules
> jetified-google-webrtc-1.0.25003-runtime
> (org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.25003) and
> jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.84.0-jitsi-5385907-runtime
> (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.84.0-jitsi-5385907)
> Duplicate class org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder$1 found in modules
> jetified-google-webrtc-1.0.25003-runtime
> (org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.25003) and
> jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.84.0-jitsi-5385907-runtime
> (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.84.0-jitsi-5385907)
> Duplicate class org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder$DecodedTextureMetadata
> found in modules jetified-google-webrtc-1.0.25003-runtime
> (org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.25003) and
> jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.84.0-jitsi-5385907-runtime
> (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.84.0-jitsi-5385907)
> Duplicate class org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder$FrameInfo found in
> modules jetified-google-webrtc-1.0.25003-runtime
> (org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.25003) and
> jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.84.0-jitsi-5385907-runtime
> (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.84.0-jitsi-5385907)
> Duplicate class org.webrtc.AudioProcessingFactory found in modules
> jetified-google-webrtc-1.0.25003-runtime
> (org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.25003) and
> jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.84.0-jitsi-5385907-runtime
> (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.84.0-jitsi-5385907)
> Duplicate class org.webrtc.AudioSource found in modules
> jetified-google-webrtc-1.0.25003-runtime
> (org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.25003) and
> jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.84.0-jitsi-5385907-runtime
> (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.84.0-jitsi-5385907)
> Duplicate class org.webrtc.AudioTrack found in modules
> jetified-google-webrtc-1.0.25003-runtime
> (org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.25003) and
> jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.84.0-jitsi-5385907-runtime
> (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.84.0-jitsi-5385907)
> Duplicate class org.webrtc.BaseBitrateAdjuster found in modules
> jetified-google-webrtc-1.0.25003-runtime
> (org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.25003) and
> jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.84.0-jitsi-5385907-runtime
> (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.84.0-jitsi-5385907)
> Duplicate class org.webrtc.BitrateAdjuster found in modules
> jetified-google-webrtc-1.0.25003-runtime
> (org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.25003) and
> jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.84.0-jitsi-5385907-runtime
> (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.84.0-jitsi-5385907)
> Duplicate class org.webrtc.CallSessionFileRotatingLogSink found in
> modules jetified-google-webrtc-1.0.25003-runtime
> (org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.25003) and
> jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.84.0-jitsi-5385907-runtime
> (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.84.0-jitsi-5385907)
> Duplicate class org.webrtc.CalledByNative found in modules
> jetified-google-webrtc-1.0.25003-runtime
> (org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.25003) and
> jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.84.0-jitsi-5385907-runtime
> (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.84.0-jitsi-5385907)
> Duplicate class org.webrtc.CalledByNativeUnchecked found in modules
> jetified-google-webrtc-1.0.25003-runtime
> (org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.25003) and
> jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.84.0-jitsi-5385907-runtime
> (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.84.0-jitsi-5385907)
> Duplicate class org.webrtc.Camera1Capturer found in modules
> jetified-google-webrtc-1.0.25003-runtime

Answer (score 5):

Probably a late answer but for future reference, both of the dependencies are using `WebRtc` as a transitive dependency and thus duplicate classes

```
implementation ('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:2.10.0') {
    transitive = true
    exclude group: 'com.facebook.react', module: 'react-native-webrtc'
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the same error but couldn't get it work. `Duplicate class org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder found in modules jetified-sinch-android-rtc-3.17.5-runtime (sinch-android-rtc-3.17.5.aar) and jetified-voximplant-sdk-2.27.0-runtime (com.voximplant:voximplant-sdk:2.27.0)`
Tried >
`implementation(project(':react-native-voximplant')){
        transitive = true
        exclude group: 'com.voximplant', module:'org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder'
}`

Comment: @AnnieTan I had to dig deeper into `org.jitsi.react` jar to find the duplicate classes that were causing the problem. In your case, it's a totally different library that you are using. Therefore, this answer will not work for you. You have to figure out duplicates in the Jar file and exclude them using `exclude group`.